# fxFlex and truncate span if overflows is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with my flex div and it's span inside.

I want it to be truncate when text overflows, the text is truncated and overflow is hidden, but ellipsis is not shown.

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="over-line">
    <div fxFlex="0 0 60%" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
       <div class="truncate" fxLayoutAlign="start center">{{ mytext }}</div>
    </div>
</div>

.truncate {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

in my research I read I needed to use min-width:0 but it doesnt work.

based on the answer I have, that the problem is I'm using a span, I updated it to div, but same result

where can be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Span is an inline element. Give display block and assign some value as width**

```css
.truncate {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50px; 
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="over-line">
    <div fxFlex="0 0 60%" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
       <span class="truncate" fxLayoutAlign="start center">{{mytext}} pakistan</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i do this i'm not able to center it vertically, how could i do it?

Comment: Try to give height say 40px to class name .truncate And we center the text using this trick .over-line > div { display:flex; align-items:center;}